# React : flattenchildren(...): encountered two children with the same key

Tags: reactjs, key

I have an input element with following markup

index comes from property

```
<input type='text'  key={`string-${index}`}  name ={`string-${index}`}    value={this.state[`string-${index}`]}  />
```

as and when i click on input text, i get flattenchildren(...): encountered two children with the same key.

How to fix this warning in console.

Comment: Don't have child elements with the same key? Hard to say since we can't really think about what's generating the problematic elements.

Comment: Yeah, we need to see where that index is coming from.  Is it coming from a `map` or your database?

Comment: @StephenL  it is coming from for loop

Comment: Can you add code around this?